# mongodb shard a collection in the background

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have a collection with about 88 million records.
The size of the collection is about 9440 Mb.
This collection is now placed on 1 shard (with Replication)
Now because of disk shortage I have to distribute this collection on 3 available shards (with replication).

This is my Database:

```
 Database_name = SensorData
 Collection_name = Values
 Index : 
  [
    {"v":1,"key":{"_id":1},"name":"_id_","ns":"SensorData.Values"},
    {"v":1,"key":{"i":1},"name":"i_1","ns":"SensorData.Values"},
    {"v":1,"key":{"i":1,"date":1},"name":"i_1_date_1","ns":"SensorData.Values"}
  ]
 Shard collections =
    {  "_id" : "set1",  "host" : "set1/***.***.***.35:27018,***.***.***.30:27018" }
    {  "_id" : "set2",  "host" : "set2/***.***.***.162:27018,***.***.***.33:27018" }
    {  "_id" : "set3",  "host" : "set3/***.***.***.174:27018,***.***.***.27:27018" }
```

I tried the following commands, but the my database will freeze.

```
sh.status()
     {  "_id" : "SensorData",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "set1" }
sh.enableSharding("SensorData")
     { "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "already enabled" }
sh.shardCollection("SensorData.Values", {i: 1} )
```

With the last command the database will freeze after a while.

My question is: Is this the right way and can I shard this collection on the background so that data which is placed in this collection will not be effected. (or slightly effected)

Comment: a) Yes. b) Not that I am aware of, being a certified (2.6) DBA. c) This is exactly the reason why architecture planning is one of the few things you can not do on the fly with MongoDB.

Answer (score 1):

My advice for you is to put your application in maintenance for the time of the operation and simply do the following :

- Don't change anything to the current collection.
- Create a new sharded collection with the shard key you want and add all the other indexes you will want on it.
- Run a script to copy your data from the initial collection to the new one which is correctly sharded across your cluster.
- Remove the old collection.
- Rename the new collection to the initial name.

Eventually, you can improve the speed of the copy step by preheating your new  collection to force the chunks creation across your cluster to make sure you won't only rely on the balancer to do all the work because initially, there is only one chunk stored on one of the shard and it will take all the writes for a while until the balancer can rebalance your chunks across the cluster.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't understand. Is it a question ?